# Requests.get fails even though a direct SSL connection works

Tags: python, c++, ssl

I have been playing around with HTTPS in C++ and have written a basic server. The server does not care about the request and only sends one possible reply. I tried to connect using the `get()` method of the Python [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module to test my server. However this raised the error `certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate` on the client (python) side and `123145338105856:error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 48` on the server (C++) side. When I tried to connect using this code:

```py
import socket, ssl

s = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM), server_side = False)
s.connect(("website.com", 443)) # Not the actual website
s.send(b'e') # As I mentioned, the server does not care about the request
print(s.recv(16384))
```

or this code:

```sh
openssl s_client -connect website.com:443 # Again, not the actual website
```

Everything went to plan.

I have found that the error is raised in `SSL_accept()`. Here is some code from the server that i think is important:

```cpp
// The SSL context initialiser

SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());

if (!ctx)
    throw errors::SSLError();

if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "server.crt", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0)
    throw errors::SSLError();

if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "server.key", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 )
    throw errors::SSLError();

this->ctx = ctx;
this->fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

```cpp
// The accept function

SSL *ssl = SSL_new(this->ctx);
SSL_set_verify(ssl, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
SSL_set_fd(ssl, accept(this->fd, (struct sockaddr *) this->addr, &this->slen));

if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) // This fails
    throw errors::SSLError(ssl);
```

Update: It works on the Safari browser too

Comment: Have you tried `TLSv1_2_server_method()` or `TLS_server_method()` instead of `SSLv23_server_method()`?

Comment: Sadly that did not work.

Comment: Too bad. I was hoping since it said something about `tls1` up there. :-)